# How to parse several log nginx files using goaccess

Tags: logging, nginx, goaccess

I want to parse all my logs of nginx (you can see here):

```
ls /var/log/nginx/
access.log    access.log.21.gz  error.log.1      error.log.22.gz
access.log.1      access.log.22.gz  error.log.10.gz  error.log.23.gz
access.log.10.gz  access.log.23.gz  error.log.11.gz  error.log.24.gz
access.log.11.gz  access.log.24.gz  error.log.12.gz  error.log.2.gz
access.log.12.gz  access.log.2.gz   error.log.13.gz  error.log.3.gz
access.log.13.gz  access.log.3.gz   error.log.14.gz  error.log.4.gz
access.log.14.gz  access.log.4.gz   error.log.15.gz  error.log.5.gz
access.log.15.gz  access.log.5.gz   error.log.16.gz  error.log.6.gz
access.log.16.gz  access.log.6.gz   error.log.17.gz  error.log.7.gz
access.log.17.gz  access.log.7.gz   error.log.18.gz  error.log.8.gz
access.log.18.gz  access.log.8.gz   error.log.19.gz  error.log.9.gz
access.log.19.gz  access.log.9.gz   error.log.20.gz
access.log.20.gz  error.log     error.log.21.gz
```

but I don't know how to do that. First of all, it seems like goaccess can't parse .gz files.

What's the best way of parse all the information contained in these logs?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Quoting the [**man page**](https://goaccess.io/man#examples) and assuming you have a Combined Log Format:

> If we would like to process all access.log.*.gz we can do one of the following:

```
# zcat -f access.log* | goaccess --log-format=COMBINED
```

OR

```
# zcat access.log.*.gz | goaccess --log-format=COMBINED
```

On Mac OS X, use `gunzip -c` instead of `zcat`.

Comment: `zcat -f access.log* | goaccess` is enough